# NHibernate fetch="join" mapping attribute does not appear to work

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

Mapping a dictionary with NH. Declaration is as follows:

```
<hibernate-mapping ...
    <map 
        name="CostsByRole" 
        table="JobAccountingSnapshotCosts"
        lazy="false" 
        fetch="join" 
        access="nosetter.camelcase-underscore">
            <key column="SnapshotId" />
            <index column="RoleCode" type="String" />
            <element column="Amount" type="Decimal" />
    </map>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

I am expecting a single SQL query to be generated but instead I get two: a select for the actual object, followed by a select for the contents of the dictionary.

Any ideas?

Comment: Um... whoever downvoted, maybe you could explain why? looks like a legit question to me.

Comment: Is join="fetch" in your mapping a typo?

Comment: I just reformatted verbatim, it was there originally.

Comment: Yup, it was a typo, now corrected -- thank you for catching it!

Comment: So was fixing the typo the solution? Or was that just an issue with writing the question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

HQL queries do not consider the values set for fetch in the mapping. You need to specify them exclusively in each HQL query. Its supposedly by design. The fetch attributes value is used only by Criteria queries and by Load/Get.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming it's not a typo on submission, the problem is likely to be the `join="fetch"` part in your mapping. It should be `fetch="join"` and since the default for `fetch` is "select", that would yield your sequential select problem.

Comment: Indeed, it was a typo (thank you for catching that!), now corrected.