# Can NHibernate solve N+1 without using batching or Criteria API for an Order->Customer relationship?

Tags: c#, .net, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, many-to-one

I have been reading and looking around to find this answer in black and white.

> Let's talk about the familiar
>   `Customer` and `Order` problem. Let's
>   say I load 100 orders, and each order
>   is linked to one and only one
>   customer.

Using Fluent NHibernate, I will use `References()` to link my `Order` to `Customer` and I will define my `Not.LazyLoad()` and `Fetch.Join()` as well.

Now I am thinking hypothetically, NHibernate can simply join these two tables and would be pretty easy to hydrate entities. However, in my tests I always see rather N+1 queries (in fact perhaps only the unique IDs). I can share my code and tables but it might bore you, so

- Is it possible to overcome N+1 for Order->Customer (one->one or rather Many->One)? Or I have to use batching or Criteria API?
- If possible can you please point me to an Fluent NHibernate example?

Comment: 2 queries and N+1 queries are only the same thing when there is only one item. If a customer has ten orders, do you see 11 selects?

Comment: It is N+1. I have updated the question. Although it is only unique values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Frequently there is the complain that [fetch="join" doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/655520/nhibernate-fetch-join-mapping-attribute-does-not-appear-to-work). This is because it is not considered by HQL. You can declare it within HQL.

I used fetch="join" hoping to make performance better but stopped using it in many cases. The problem was that joining to many tables could make SQL server run into a maximal number of columns limit. In some cases you don't need the data at all and therefore it is not very useful to specify it globally in the mapping file.

So I would recommend to

- either use explicit join fetching in HQL, because there you know if the data is actually used.
- or for any other case, batches are a great solution, because they are transparent (your code doesn't need to know about), make use of lazy loading and reducing the N+1 problem at the same time.

Comment: The answer is: use explicit join fetching in HQL if you don't want to use batching.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't look at the mapping as much as the actual querying you are doing.  I leave ALL of my mappings as LazyLoad by default and override as needed.

I use the Criteria API to query, and I use CreateAlias to join other tables as needed.  NHProf is highly recommended to find and eliminate situations like this.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, but I do not fancy using a pre-Linq language. So do you mean that without using Criteria API, there is no way?

Comment: If you really want to use Linq, you can use the Expand method: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/831794/linq-for-nhibernate-and-fetch-mode-of-eager-loading

Comment: BTW, what version on NHibernate are you using?  Pre 3's linq provider left a little to be desired.

Comment: Did you try the Expand method?  I know that works in 2.0.  Not sure about 3.0.

Answer (score 2):

Hi
There are two ways you can address your problem

a) Using Criteria query
It will look something like this

```
Session.CreateQuery(typeof(Order))
.Add(<Restrictions if any>)
.SetFetchMode("Customer",FetchMode.Eager)
.List<Order>();
```

b)  Using HQL

```
Session.CreateQuery("select o from Order inner join fetch o.Customer where <conditionifany>").List<Order>();
```

Hope this helps..

Answer (score 0):

What query API are you using?

If it's HQL, you can use `join fetch` to retrieve an association eagerly.

For LINQ and QueryOver, use `.Fetch()`